Group By a field with a DataRaptor Transform
I'm attempting to group Quote Lines in the JSON output of a DataRaptor Extract with a Transform and am unsure if this is possible without an Integration Procedure.
I currently have Quote Lines outputting as such:
    "QuoteLine": [
    {
      "ProductSiteName": "BO1",
      "ProductId": "Prod1",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Number": 1,
      "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
    },
    {
      "ProductSiteName: "S0-1",
      "ProductId": "Prod2",
      "Quantity": 15,
      "Number": 2,
      "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
    } ...

and would like to transform that to group based on the ProductSiteName as such:
    "Site" : [
    {
      "ProductSiteName": "BO1"
      "QuoteLine": [
      {
        "ProductId": "Prod1",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Number": 1,
        "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
      }
    },
    {
      "ProductSiteName": "S0-1",
      "QuoteLine": [
      {
        "ProductId": "Prod2",
        "Quantity": 15,
        "Number": 2,
        "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
      }
    } ...

I'm relatively new to OmniScripts and feel like I might be already incorrect at the Extract level.

You will need to use an Integration Procedure to accomplish the required transformation.
High level steps are:

Extract all Quote Lines
Use a Dataraptor Transform to extract unique values for ProductSiteName.

This can be done by passing in the Quoteline list to the DR Transform, using the formula LISTMERGE("ProductSiteName",LIST(%QuoteLine%)) to "extract" the unique ProductSiteName values and then let the DR Transform return a list of all the unique ProductSiteName values:


The output will look like:
[
  {
    "ProductSiteName": "BO1"
  },
  {
    "ProductSiteName": "S0-1"
  }
]


Loop over these values using a Loop Block:

Create another Integration Procedure that accepts a ProductSiteName value as well as the list of Quote Lines
Use the FILTER formula to Extract all Quote Lines for the given ProductSiteName e.g. FILTER(LIST(%QuoteLine%),'ProductSiteName=="S0-1"') (see here for how to use a variable as the search term)
Use the Response Action to return the JSON for a given ProductSiteName in the required format:



{
  "ProductSiteName": "S0-1",
  "QuoteLine": [
  {
    "ProductId": "Prod2",
    "Quantity": 15,
    "Number": 2,
    "Quote": "a5LQL0000001k8r2AA"
  }
}


In the Parent Integration Procedure build the final output from the Loop Block and return it using a Response Action.

Good luck!

Thank you for the help! For step 2, how would I remove duplicates?

@ivcv I edited the answer to expand on how to remove duplicates for step 2.

Thanks for responding. The issue I'm getting now is with the Input JSON Path. If I just output the formula, I correctly get a list of nodes of each unique ProductSiteName, but when I append ":ProductSiteName", it just gives a single value (whatever ProductSiteName is first in the list) instead of the example output you gave. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

nvm - realized I could just pass in another list with only the ProductSiteName for each node. Thank you so much for the help!

@ivcv if this was helpful I would really appreciate it if you mark my response as the answer

Please , I m new Integration Procedure , I don't get it for the 3.2 Step on the answer , How can I Use a List Action to Extract all Quote Lines for the given ProductSiteName, How to configure that. Thanks
